# Changing 8 column type of a big table from nvarchar(max) to varchar(x) with EF code Code-first

Tags: sql-server, migration, ef-code-first, nvarchar

I have a very big table(T1) with a Tera byte of data in the Prod environment. There are some columns with nvarchar(max) which are such a miss. The table is created by code-first Ef core. Since it is very time-consuming to do it with migration we want to do it by:

1. creating a new table (T2) with new types for those columns like varchar(100) with code-first.
2. Copying all data from T1 to T2 (DBA process) (needs downtime)
3. Renaming those with code-first and creating migration file
4. Exporting script of step 3 and run it directly in Database with DBAs
5. After achieving success in step 4 update the database with the renaming migration. Since changes were done in step 4 and we have the migration record in the database table it will execute quickly.
6. Now we can drop the T1 with migration
7. Exporting its script and run it directly in the database
8. Updating database with step 7 migration

So do you have such experience or idea to add?

Comment: Isn't it better to create new columns in same table (T1) with correct datatypes, and copy them one by one and then drop original column and finally rename the new columns? It will still take a lot of time, but at least you don't have to copy whole T1

Comment: What's actually is your question?

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve here? If you're trying to correlate "max" with your terabyte of data - values of `varbinary(max)`, `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` are in-row data until they exceed 8000 bytes, only then do they go to LOB storage.

Comment: i think he doesn't wanna do alter table alter nvarcharMaxColumn varchar(20) because it will "take forever"

Comment: @siggemannen of course we can use this approach too. But it will take too much time and it may need downtime since it is in the Production environment.

Comment: @siggemannen of course, we can use this approach too. But it will take too much time and it may need downtime since it is in the Production environment. But let's consider this. 
1. Creating new columns with new names (run with DBAs) in T1. 
2. Copying data from old columns to the new ones (run with DBAs) 
3. Altering T1 and removing old columns (run with DBAs). 
4. Renaming columns (with DBAs). 
5. Create a migration for changing columns' type  (Developer EF code-first) 
(NOTE: Since the database has been changed, if we update DB with migration it will be done immediately but not sure).

Comment: Now the question is after the DB changes have been done, what could be the behavior of EF core after running the update-database PMC command?  (The migration file has 8 ALTER COLUMN commands)

Comment: I would do it the above way. But I'm pure sql developer so I don't know about "migration" parts